# Angular Material: error TS2339: Property 'menu' does not exist on type 'TableComponent'

Tags: angular, angular-material

Im using Angular Material to build a table, which is supposed to have a menu and menu items for each row in the table. The `.html` file is

```
<!-- action column -->
<ng-container *ngIf="rowActionIcon?.length" [matColumnDef]="rowActionIcon">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  <td mat-cell class="action-column" *matCellDef="let element" [id]="rowActionIcon" (click)="emitRowAction(element)">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
      <mat-icon>{{rowActionIcon}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu" *ngFor="let action of menuActions">
      <button mat-menu-item>{{action}}</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

But the compiler is complaining that

```
error TS2339: Property 'menu' does not exist on type 'TableComponent'.
19                     <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
                                                               ~~~~
```

If i look at the documentation for menu, I can't see any declarations of this specific attribute in the examples:
https://material.angular.io/components/menu/examples

Im obviously missing something (noob at Angular and Material) but I thought `menu` in the button referred to the `#menu` DOM element in the `<mat-menu>` tag?

I have no specification of the MatMenu in the ts file. Do I need to add that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your problem is with *ngFor because you create many menus, try this

```
<ng-container *ngIf="rowActionIcon?.length" [matColumnDef]="rowActionIcon">
  <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef></th>
  <td mat-cell class="action-column" *matCellDef="let element" [id]="rowActionIcon" (click)="emitRowAction(element)">
    <button mat-button [matMenuTriggerFor]="menu">
      <mat-icon>{{rowActionIcon}}</mat-icon>
    </button>
    <mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
      <button mat-menu-item *ngFor="let action of menuActions">{{action}}</button>
    </mat-menu>
  </td>
</ng-container>
```

Comment: I want to create one menu per item in the table, {{rowActionIcon}} should be the icon to click to open each menu

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is in ngFor:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu" *ngFor="let action of menuActions">
   <button mat-menu-item>{{action}}</button>
</mat-menu>
```

You can replace it with:

```
<mat-menu #menu="matMenu">
   <button *ngFor="let action of menuActions" mat-menu-item>{{action}}</button>
</mat-menu>
```